# LWCs are not available in sandbox (Where they are deployed)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-flow-builder

Losing my mind folks! I have a very basic LWC deployed to my sandbox but both Flow Builder and App Builder do not see them. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help appreciated!

.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Payment Component</masterLabel>
    <description>Component for creating transactions</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
       <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
       <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
       <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class PaymentScreenLWC extends LightningElement {
    uselessFunc() {
        console.log('something')
    }
}
```

.html

```
<template>
    TEST
</template>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with component code, are you sure its pushed to sandbox?https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_setup

Comment: Can you please add <targetConfigs> for flow
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Comment: Added ```<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Invoice__c</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>``` to the meta, made no difference in the app builder

Comment: @AnmolKumar yes it is listed in Lightning Components

Comment: You should be searching for `Payment Component` instead of the actual component name as you have mentioned that in `masterLabel`

Comment: @rahulgawale just created a scratch org and pushed the basic LWC and it shows up in flow and app builder without any extra configuration. So Im assuming my sandbox org is just broken or somethign...

Answer (score 0):

So I deleted all my LWCs from source and org, and then created ANOTHER new, barebones LWC and set it up like in my example and pushed it and everything works now. No idea what the actual problem was but if you have this issue, give this a try.